# React Native Elements Icon Not Showing On Button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Hi,**

I am trying to use a Icon in the `React-Native-Elements` [Button](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html) component. I am not getting errors or warnings but I just end up with a empty button.

Here is some of my code containing the Button:

```
<Col size={20}>
    <Button icon={<Icon name="heart" color="#00aced"/>} size={30} buttonStyle={style.button}/>
</Col>
```

I hope someone can help me because I am not sure why it doesn't show up.

**Thanks in advance!**

More information as requested:

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const style = {
   button: {
        backgroundColor: '#6A5ACD',
        borderRadius: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      }
}
```

I've also tried other imports like Fontawesome.

Comment: not enough information. What are the props? What's in 'style.button'? did you import the icon from fontawesome or another library?

Comment: @RachelGallen I've edited the post. The props are described [here](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html).

Comment: why are you importing Icon from react-native-elements? Import BUTTON from elements, and the Icon from fontawesome

Comment: I didn't mean props in general, i meant what props have you used in your code..like what's in your onPress etc..  maybe spend an hour or so reviewing your code..

Comment: @RachelGallen Already did that. Didn't work.

Comment: @RachelGallen The above code are all props that I use. There is nothing in my onPress.

Comment: Already did what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173677/discussion-between-kittycat-and-rachel-gallen).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:--

```
<Col size={20}>
    <Button 
    icon={{name: 'envira', type: 'font-awesome'}} 
    size={30} buttonStyle={style.button}/>
</Col>
```

If still not getting icon then you have to install the 'react-native-vector-icons'

```
-- npm install react-native-vector-icons --save 
-- react-native link
```

Comment: Already tried that, but I get this warning, (not a error): `Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'name' of value '[object Object]' supplied to 'Icon', expected one of: --Allot of icon names--`

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/138

Run

```
react-native link
react-native run-android
```

Comment: You can use npx also: `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 3):

for me the Icons were showing perfectly in IOS but in Android it was not getting displayed but

```
react-native link
```

did the trick

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused by the deprecated/older version of react-native link.

For fix: Open android/app/build.gradle and add the following:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it arrow func. This work for me

```
icon={() => <Icon name="chevron-thin-down" size={18} />}
```