# react-native-vector-icons/ react-native-elements not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

I have tried everything but cannot resolve this error. Please Help to replace this [box instead of icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixkNJ.jpg)
`import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'`
`<Icon name="glass" ></Icon>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Over Flow, please post your code you have tried, it could let us more easily to help you.

Comment: You could edit at your post just under your question have a `edit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this:

```js
import FontAwesome from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
...

<FontAwesome
    name={"glass"}
    size={30}
    color="#000000" 
/>
```

[Code example on expo](https://snack.expo.io/3B5Id!yUr)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use react-native-elements you should try to use it with props *type*, like this:

```
<Icon
    name='glass'
    type='font-awesome'
    onPress={() => console.log('hello')}
/>
```

If the icon is still not displayed you have to try this:

```
react-native link
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166771/7225869)